# My brother often practiced or practices the violin in the afternoon?

Tags: tense

**My brother often practiced the violin in the afternoon. But he didn't yesterday because he was ill.**

I wonder if it's suitable to use practiced here. I think yesterday's absence from practicing the violin doesn't necessarily mean the habit has changed. So to use practices makes much sense.

Answer (score 3):

The present tense is correct.  This a normal habit that is generally true so the simple present tense is the right tense to use.

You would only use the past tense for a habit that has now finished.

> When he was a boy, my brother practised the violin most afternoons.  Now he is a maths teacher, so he doesn't have time for musical instruments.

Note that in [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english), the spelling of "practised" should use "s" not "c" (s in the verb, c in the noun)